# How to run a Firestore query inside a map function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and Firebase and I am trying to build my first app. I am storing Game documents in Firestore and one of the fields is an array containing the user ids of the players as you can see in the image.

[Game data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv8Gh.png)

That being said, I am trying to list all games of a given user and have all the players listed in each one of the cells (the order is important).

In order to create the list of games in the UI I created a GameCellListView and a GameCellViewModel. The GameCellViewModel should load both the games and the array of users that correspond to the players of each game. However I am not being able to load the users to an array. I have to go through the players array and query the database for each Id and append to a User array; then I should be able to return this User array. Since I'm using a for loop, I can't assign the values to the array and then return it. I tried using map(), but I can't perform a query inside of it.
The goal is to load that "all" var with a struct that receives a game and its players `GamePlayers(players: [User], game: Game)`

It should look something like the code snippet below, but the users array always comes empty. This function runs on GameCellViewModel init.
I hope you can understand my problem and thank you in advance! Been stuck on this for 2 weeks now

```
func loadData() {
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        db.collection("games")
            .order(by: "createdTime")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId)
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                self.games = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                    do {
                        let extractedGame = try document.data(as: Game.self)
                        var user = [User]()
                        let users = extractedGame!.players.map { playerId -> [User] in

                            self.db.collection("users")
                                .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: playerId)
                            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                                    print("No documents")
                                    return
                                }
                                user = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> User? in
                                    return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: User.self)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            return user
                        }
                        
                        self.all.append(GamePlayers(players: users.first ?? [User](), game: extractedGame!))

                        
                        return extractedGame
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Well first, this isn't a SwiftUI question; it is plain Swift so your title will mislead people. However, you are going to need to show your models, etc. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Another issue is you are using `try?` without a `do, catch` so any errors are being lost, so you are losing out on information that could help debug.

Comment: @Yrb thanks for the suggestion! I am not using do, catch but this is just to showcase what I wish that could happen. My major issue is that I can't update the self.all because I am not able to go through an array of ids and query the corresponding users and append them to an array

Comment: I don't use Firestore, so I can't comment on its quirks, but obviously you are having a complete failure to return any objects from your closure.

Comment: @Yrb Do you have any suggestions on how should I do it?

Comment: @Yrb I think my question is more related to swift than firestore. If I print the users inside of the {} I can see the correct query results. I just can't append them to an array

Comment: `array.append(element)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of moving parts in your code and so to isolate points of failure would require seeing additional code so just be aware of that upfront.  That said, if you are relatively new to Firestore or Swift then I would strongly suggest you first get a handle on this function using basic syntax. Once you're comfortable with the ins and outs of async looping then I would suggest refactoring the code using more advanced syntax, like you have here.

Your function requires performing async work within each loop iteration (of each document). You actually need to do this twice, async work within a loop within a loop. Be sure this is what you really want to do before proceeding because there may be cleaner ways, which may include a more efficient NoSQL data architecture. Regardless, for the purposes of this function, start with the most basic syntax there is for the job which is the Dispatch Group in concert with the for-loop. Go ahead and nest these until you have it working and then consider refactoring.

```
func loadData() {
    // Always safely unwrap the user ID and never assume it is there.
    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }
    // Query the database.
    db.collection("games").whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId).order(by: "createdTime").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
            // We need to loop through a number of documents and perform
            // async tasks within them so instantiate a Dispatch Group
            // outside of the loop.
            let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
            
            for doc in querySnapshot.documents {
                // Everytime you enter the loop, enter the dispatch.
                dispatch.enter()
                
                do {
                    // Do something with this document.
                    // You want to perform an additional async task in here,
                    // so fire up another dispatch and repeat these steps.
                    // Consider partitioning these tasks into separate functions
                    // for readability.

                    // At some point in this do block, we must leave the dispatch.
                    dispatch.leave()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    
                    // Everytime you leave this iteration, no matter the reason,
                    // even on error, you must leave the dispatch.
                    dispatch.leave()
                    
                    // If there is an error in this iteration, do not return.
                    // Return will return out of the method itself (loadData).
                    // Instead, continue, which will continue the loop.
                    continue
                }
            }
            
            dispatch.notify(queue: .main) {
                // This is the completion handler of the dispatch.
                // Your first round of data is ready, now proceed.
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            // Always log errors to console!!!
            // This should be automatic by now without even having to think about it.
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I also noticed that within the second set of async tasks within the second loop, you're adding snapshot listeners. Are you really sure you want to do this? Don't you just need a plain document get?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will implement this in a few hours and check if it works for my. I used dispatching groups once and it froze the app, but it was slightly different from your suggestion. Could you provide the "correct" way of doing this? Even if it requires changing the data structure. I can include more code, so that you can have a better understanding. Thanks again!